# Calculus Derivative Question

Tags: calculus

Hi guys I'm really stuck on this question, it is a practice question for my calculus exam 
so any help with it would be great! I just feel their is a lack of information in this question. Thanks in advance!

If s is measured in meters, the value of a is approximately 9:8. How many seconds
do you have to get out of the way of a chandelier which falls from a 100-meter
ceiling? If you don't make it, how fast will the chandelier be going when it hits
you? Where was the chandelier when it was moving with half that speed?

Comment: I have added a sketch of the solution below... please feel free to ask questions, but I think that these answers will be more than enough to inspire the complete solutions.

Comment: @ChrisK Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ChrisK Hi Chris is there any way I could see the sketch?

Comment: perhaps I used the wrong word. I meant an outline when I said a sketch. Does the solution make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Well, $a(t) = x''(t) = 9.8$ and so $x(t) = 9.8/2\cdot t^{2}+v(0)\cdot t +x(0) = 4.9t^{2}$. So, $t = \sqrt{100/4.9}$, which is approximately $2\cdot \sqrt{5}$. So a good approximation for $v$ is: $v_{final} = 9.8t = 19.6\sqrt{5}.$ Finally, the chandelier will have travelled $(1/2)^{2} = 1/4$ of the distance when it was moving at half the speed.